Surjectivity of $h:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $h(x,y):=mx+ny$
Let $h:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ be defined by $h(x,y):=mx+ny$, where $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$. What is the range of this function, and under what conditions is $\operatorname{Range}(h)=\mathbb{Z}$? I think that I have established that $h$ is injective iff $m\neq 0\neq n$ (I could be wrong!). However, establishing conditions for surjectivity is a bit of a challenge at the moment. Any ideas are welcome.

Hint: What happens when the coefficients have a common factor? For example, what is the range when $(m, n) = (30, 20)$? Can you find an (infinite) set of preimages of each integer in the range? Can you find numbers not in the range?

How about $f(n,-m)$ and $f(-n,m)$? For surjectivity: hint: $\gcd(m,n)$.

How have you "established that $h$ is injective iff $m\neq 0\neq n$"? ($f(n,-m)=f(0,0)$). (Non-)injectivity is anyway irrelevant for your exercise. + Please add some context

See here in tke linked dupe for the solvability criterion for linear Diophantine equation. $\ \ $

Your post is a duplicate of Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash { 0}$. Prove there exists $x$, $y$ such that $ax+by=c$ if and only if $(a,b)|c$.

It can't be injective: $\Bbb Z$ doesn't contain a copy of $\Bbb Z×\Bbb Z.$
To be surjective requires hitting one of the generators,  $\pm1.$  This in turn requires $(m,n)=1.$
